# Android. Падает приложение, при нажатии меню

Tags: java

При выборе любого меню, в телефоне вылетает ошибка, и приложение рушится. У меня есть активити `MainActivity(MainActivity{activity_main.xml} )`, из которого по кнопкам есть переход в активити `SecondActivity (SecondActivity.java{activity_second.xml} )`, а уже из меню `SecondActivity`(не кнопки) попадаем в активити `DetailActivity`, где и должен находится текст. В первой активити `res/layout/activity_second.xml` добавлен компонент `ListView` для отображения списка тем::

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SecondActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

Затем создана разметка для `activity_detail.xml` (Скрытие строки состояния и заголовка  в Java-коде.)

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Дизайн приложения готов. 
теперь файл класса SecondActivity (Заголовки и тд.)Цель:Когда пользователь выбирает элемент списка, то мы получаем позицию выбранного элемента и запоминаем его. А затем запускаем вторую активность, в которую передаём номер позиции.

```
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
//Создаем массив разделов:
private String head_array[] = {
        "00. Начало",
        "01. лялялля ",
        "02. лялялялял",
        "03. лялялялля",
        "04. ляляллял.",
        "05. ялялялялял",
        "06. ялялялялял",
        "07. ялялялялялял",
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    // Получим идентификатор ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    //устанавливаем массив в ListView
    listView.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, head_array));
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    //Обрабатываем щелчки на элементах ListView:
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(SecondActivity.this, detailactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("head", position);
            //запускаем вторую активность
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

## }

Затем в ресурсах создаем папку `raw`, и туда кладем текстовые файлы `n0.html`, `n1.html` (`n2.txt` и `n3.txt` для проверки, но все равно приложение рушится, при выборе меню).
Код для второй активити `detailactivity.java`:

```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.webkit.WebView;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

   public class detailactivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
    String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
    Log.i("name", resName);
    Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

    //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.example.carcar"));

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
}

//читаем текст из raw-ресурсов
public static String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

## }

Может поглядите, в чем ошибка, или предложите свой более простой выход отобразить информацию из меню, а то в телефоне по кнопке я перехожу во второе окно, там вижу меню, нажимаю на любой пункт из меню, после чего происходит ошибка приложения, и как итог - закрытие программы.

Comment: Меню вы нигде не используете, наверное имtете в виду элементы списка в ListView. Классы именуются с большой буквы, получать Context в активити методом getBaseContext() не нужно, т.к. в активити контекст это просто this. Без указания логов ошибки и точной строки её возникновения помочь вам практически невозможно.

Comment: ошибок eclips не выдает... напротив компиляция проходит в стандартном режиме без нареканий... но при установке в смартфон и установке приложения он переходит и за ктивити к списку элемента LidtView (любому) и пишется ошибка приложения и все закрывается.

Comment: Повторюсь - без логов ошибки помочь вам практически невозможно.

Comment: ошибку нашел. забыл активити прописать в манифесте... думал что прописал а на деле нет.

Comment: Напишите это в ответе - может кому-нибудь ещё это пригодится в будущем)